# Travis-CI: Multiple schemes for iOS, OSX, tvOS and watchOS

Tags: ios, macos, travis-ci

I have an Xcode workspace that builds frameworks for iOS, OS X, tvOS and watchOS.  I would like to have Travis build all four, but I cannot figure out how to specify multiple values for xcode_scheme and xcode_sdk in the travis.yml file.

For example, the .travis.yml might look something like this (but this only builds for OS X):

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
xcode_workspace: VirtualGameController.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerIOS
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.2
xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerOSX
xcode_sdk: macosx10.11
```

My project is located here:
[Virtual Game Controller](http://language:%20objective-c%20osx_image:%20xcode7.2%20xcode_workspace:%20VirtualGameController.xcworkspace%20xcode_scheme:%20VirtualGameControllerIOS%20xcode_sdk:%20iphonesimulator9.2%20c:%20VirtualGameControllerOSX%20xcode_sdk:%20macosx10.11)

Answer (score 4):

A little cleaner variant is to just **include** the desired configurations in the build matrix instead of excluding all unwanted:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
xcode_workspace: VirtualGameController.xcworkspace

matrix:
  include:
    - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerIOS
      xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.2

    - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerOSX
      xcode_sdk: macosx10.11

    - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerTvOS
      xcode_sdk: appletvsimulator

    - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerWatchOS
    - xcode_sdk: watchsimulator
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just do this:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
xcode_workspace: VirtualGameController.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme:
    - VirtualGameControllerIOS
    - VirtualGameControllerOSX
    - (other schemes)
xcode_sdk:
    - iphonesimulator9.2
    - macosx10.11
    - (other sdks)
```

Comment: That definitely took me part of the way - thanks Jack!  For that implementation, it's doing four builds, so I think maybe it's treating it as a matrix - one of the three failed.  Do you know what the syntax would be to exclude it from building the iOS project on OS X and OS X on the iPhone simulator, assuming you agree that may be the issue?

Comment: That makes sense. One workaround might be to put some checks in before the build script to look at the environment variables before building, but travis will still be doing all four builds two of them will just be doing nothing. Not sure if there's a way to define a "job" of somesort where you could define two jobs and set the environment variables on a per job basis and only run two builds, one for each job?

Comment: [This](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Multiple-Variables-per-Item) might actually be what you're looking for.

Comment: 'This' is a link in the above comment if that's unclear.

Comment: I've tried a million different approaches but nothing seems to be working.  Did my best to use environment variables - this is what I tried, but I don't think xcode_scheme and xcode_sdk do anything as env vars:       `language: objective-c
xcode_workspace: VirtualGameController.xcworkspace
osx_image: xcode7.2
env:
- xcode_sdk=iphonesimulator9.2 xcode_scheme=VirtualGameControllerIOS
- xcode_sdk=macosx10.11 xcode_scheme=VirtualGameControllerOSX
- xcode_sdk=tvos9.0 xcode_scheme=VirtualGameControllerTvOS
- xcode_sdk=watchos2.0 xcode_scheme=VirtualGameControllerWatchOS`

Comment: Finally figured out an approach that works using exclude on the build matrix.  Travis was extremely finicky about white space!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the build matrix exclude function, to prevent compiling on inappropriate platforms for a given scheme.  In targeting the 4 platforms with 4 schemes, the dynamically generated build matrix had 16 members, 12 of which were inappropriate combinations.  So I exclude those 12 combinations, and I'm left with the 4 build combinations that I was looking for.  Note that Travis seems to be very picky about white space when constructing the matrix/exclude statements:

`language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
xcode_workspace: VirtualGameController.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme:
- VirtualGameControllerIOS
- VirtualGameControllerOSX
- VirtualGameControllerTvOS
- VirtualGameControllerWatchOS
xcode_sdk:
- iphonesimulator9.2
- macosx10.11
- tvos9.0
- watchos2.0
matrix:
     exclude:
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerIOS
             xcode_sdk: macosx10.11
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerIOS
             xcode_sdk: tvos9.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerIOS
             xcode_sdk: watchos2.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerOSX
             xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.2
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerOSX
             xcode_sdk: tvos9.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerOSX
             xcode_sdk: watchos2.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerTvOS
             xcode_sdk: macosx10.11
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerTvOS
             xcode_sdk: tvos9.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerTvOS
             xcode_sdk: watchos2.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerWatchOS
             xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.2
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerWatchOS
             xcode_sdk: tvos9.0
           - xcode_scheme: VirtualGameControllerWatchOS
             xcode_sdk: watchos2.0`